# Vuetify: Make v-navigation-drawer take up all space to top left corner instead of v-app-bar

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have a VuetifyJS (v3) page with a `v-app-bar` and `v-navigation-drawer` both present, and both with the `app` prop set. The `v-app-bar` takes up all the horizontal space extending from the top left corner. The `v-navigation-drawer` starts from underneath the `v-app-bar`. How do reverse this relationship? I.e. make the `v-navigation-drawer` take up all vertical space starting from the top left corner and have the `v-app-bar` start from the side of the `v-navigation-drawer`? The [vuetifyjs.com docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/) pages actually do this (see below). So my Q is how do I do what vuetifyjs.com is doing here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for this is here: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/

The way layout components arrange themselves is controlled by the order they appear in the template, and can be adjusted with the `order` prop which behaves like [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) in CSS.